# Creating a fill animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-animation

I need find a way to create an animation that will fill and dispense a liquid inside a tube. I will need some kind of variables, such as percentages where as the percentage goes up and down the liquid rises and falls. I'm not quite sure how to do such an animation in flutter, so any help is appreciated.

I have a few pictures posted below for when the tube is empty and when it is at 180 micro liters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try with `CustomPaint` or `ClipPath` also you can check rive for complex animation.

Comment: I was actually looking into Rive, just not sure if its worth learning for just this animation. I will look into custom paint and clip path, thank you for that.

Comment: if you consider the drop, it will be easy to draw using Paint

Answer (score 5):

I had some time so I made this implementation of it:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=4e595e1950c21582dd33b4d55427a561

If dartpad.dev doesn't work, you can access the code here:

https://gist.github.com/Apaksi/4e595e1950c21582dd33b4d55427a561

Answer (score 0):

Check this

> LinearProgressIndicator,
> Timer,
> ClipPath

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer? _timer;
  int _start = 10000;

  void startTimer() {
    _start = 10000;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
        const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
        (Timer timer) =>
            setState(() => (_start == 0 ? timer.cancel() : _start--)));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
            Text('$_start'),
            RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 3,
                child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: MyClipper(),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 500,
                        height: 100,
                        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          value: (_start / 10000),
                        ))))
          ])),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => startTimer(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.2, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```